# Bibliographical reference in reverse chronological order

Tags: bibtex

I would like to have a bibliography looking like that :

[1] the most recent paper, [2] the less recent paper, [3] older paper 
etc... so in reverse chronological order with respect to the publication date.

> Is it possible to do that with LaTeX ?

I can't use

```
\usepackage[sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
```

because I use also the package multibib.

Comment: Biblatex natively supports multiple bibliographies. If multibib is the only reason not to switch, you may still consider the possibility.

Comment: @gusbrs I was not aware of that. I have to make the distinction between papers written by me and papers written by other people.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution compatible with the multibib package : http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20150324-bibtex-reverse.html (package habbrvyr.bst).